# JAVA click with mouse, move with keyboard

Tags: java, keyboard, click, mouse, jframe

I wanted to select an object inside the JFrame and move it with the keyboard arrow keys. I did the keyboard thing, whenever I pressed the arrow keys it moves accordingly to the direction. What I want is to move multiple objects. I tried to put an multiple objects and they did moved at the same time xD

**tldr; is there a way where you can click on just one object using the mouse and control it with keyboard arrow keys?**

Comment: Can you explain how you are getting the objects to move? Are you talking about components such as JButtons or some objects that you have drawn on the screen?

Comment: drawn objects. there's a class called Movable .it has the keypressed/released methods. another class Painter extends JPanel implements ActionListener it has the private class AL extends KeyAdapter w/ methods keyreleased/pressed .it also has actionperformed inside it is repaint() in the painter's constructor setfocusable true addkeylistener new al() ill upload the source

Comment: dunno but the link redirects to custom error blah blah i'll try what Sentil said :)

Comment: I removed your dead link.

Answer (score 1):

Eventhough question not clear enough, moving single or multiple objects is not a problem. You need to use KeyEvent Listener for the object you want to listen and move the components based on KeyEvent.

Here some reference: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html

Comment: i actually have keyPressed and keyRelease in those objects but the problem is they have the same conditions like when pressed left all objects will go left .is there a way where you can click on just one and that one will be the one moving?

Comment: Then you need to register listener to those each components or check the event source and move that component only. And you could make use Tab key to focus on components instead of use mouse click, if you prefered